# Google Chrome simple code injection

Tags: google-chrome

on chrome extension, im trying to add a an iframe on all websites,

currently my manifesjt.json

```
    {
  "name": "Testinjection",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Testinjection",
  "icons": {
    "48" : "sample-48.png",
    "128" : "sample-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "js" : ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and contentscript.js:

```
document.write("<iframe src=\"http:\/\/www.ask.com\" width=\"100%\" height=\"40px\"><\/iframe>");
```

The problem is that this code is replacing the current visited page and not adding this code to top,

in which way can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.write` after your page has loaded will overwrite the page. You should construct an element instead:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://www.ask.com/';
iframe.width = '100%';
iframe.height = '40px';
iframe.style.position = 'absolute';  // Add this

document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XrqvG/**

Comment: Thanks this is what i wanted,
but its breaking other websites example:
http://i49.tinypic.com/21108hx.png